# How to ignore blank lines when printing from input file using getline

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I am trying to print the contents of a file but I'm not sure how to ignore blank lines in the file.

Current code:

```
if(option == "-ps"){
        while(getline(instream, str)){
            if(str.length() == 0){
                continue;
            }
            cout << str << endl;   
        }
    }
```

File contents

```
Department meeting | 2019 |10 |29 |9:30 aM  |15 
    Meeting with Bob | 2019 |10 |29 |8:30 aM  |15 
 Meeting with Jim | 2019 |10 |29 |9:00 aM  |15 

 Doctor's appointment | 2019 |10 |29 |10:30 aM  |15 
 Meeting with Bob | 2019 |10 |29 |11:30 aM  |15 
    Lunch meeting with dean | 2019 |10 |29 |11:45 aM  |15 
 Lunch with the guys | 2019 |10 |29 |12:30 pM  |60 
    Lunch with the guys | 2019 |10 |29 |12:30 pM  |60 
 Lunch with the guys | 2019 |10 |29 |12:30 pM  |60 
 Meeting With BOB | 2019 |10 |29 |1:30 pM  |15 

 Chair meeting | 2019 |10 |29 |2:30 PM  |15 
 Meeting WITH Bob | 2019 |10 |29 |3:30 pm  |20 
  Fishing with Donald and Donald|2019|11|30|8:14AM| 115
Fishing with Donald and Billy|  2019|12|11  | 2:45 PM|15
Appointment with Donald|2019  |12|5|8:56PM |115
Appointment with Fred|2019|12|1|8:30PM|50



Lunch|2019|12  | 1|10:58PM |115
Fishing with Bob and Fred|2019 |12| 3| 2:45PM|10
Skiing with Juedes|  2019|12  | 8|9:15 am|60
```

My current code will print out the file contents but the blank lines still print as well. I tried to solve this problem with the second if statement but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The logic

```
if(str.length() == 0){
    continue;
}
```

will not work if there are lines with one or more whitespace characters. Perhaps you are running into them. You can change that to use:

```
if ( is_empty_line(line) )
{
    continue;
}
```

where

```
bool is_empty_line(const& line)
{
   for (char c : line )
   {
      if ( !std::isspace(c) )
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

You can use [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) to simplify that function.

```
bool is_empty_line(const& line)
{
   return std::all_of(line.begin(), line.end(), [](char c) { return std::isspace(c); });
}
```

Comment: very comprehensive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct , try this :

```
    getline(instream, str); 
    // Keep reading a new line while there is 
    // a blank line 
    while (str.length()==0 ) 
        getline(instream, str); 
    cout << str << << endl;
```

another way :

```
 while (getline(instream, str))
 {
  if (str== "") continue; // Skip blank line

   ... // Do stuff with non-blank line
 }
```